# How to parse XML in PHP, generating dynamic SQL insert statements

Tags: php, sql, mysql, xml, sax

I'm attempting to parse an XML file, and generate & insert the element data into a mysql database. Any pointers?
The xml document in this case is deep nested and element data contained goes into one table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with using a SimpleXML object (really easy).

Here's the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Here's a tutorial: http://www.willfitch.com/simplexml-tutorial-part1.html.

Comment: Thanks Steve, what I was actually looking for is a SAX parser. I have implemented the solution using DOM.